# Quarkus: can I share a transaction between test and application

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

From the title you'll probably tell me "use the @TestTransaction". This is not my question. As I undertand this annotation, it will rollback any changes in the db, in this case:

```
@QuarkusTest
class Test {

  @Inject val repository: Repository

  @Test
  @TestTransaction
  fun test() {
     repository.persist(MyClass(...))
}
```

Now, in the case where you want - from the test - to persist some changes and call an endpoint that also persists updates, how are we supposed to handle it?

```
@Test
@TestTransaction
fun testWithEndpoint() {
  repository.persist(MyClass(...))
  given().body(MyClass(...)).post("/save-my-class").then()...
}
```

This gives me a pessimistic lock exception, I guess because the test starts one blocking transaction, and the server cannot then get the lock. Is there any way the wrap the whole into a single transaction that would be rollbacked at the end?

Comment: No, there is no such capability.

Comment: What about context propagation? Is that not for such a case?

Comment: Nope, that is something different (although I understand why one would think it's related)